# How can I make EXE file of the modified copy?

Tags: exe, ida

I made my changes using IDA but I don't know how to make the new file exe again

Comment: are you saying "I modified an executable in IDA Pro and I want to save out the modified binary as an executable file" ?

Comment: You need to add more details for any one to answer your question

Comment: There is no reason to close this question.

Answer (score 7):

Edit -> Patch program -> Apply patches to input file.
You'll see the option to create backup too, select it and you should have to copies of your input file, the original and the new edited one.

Answer (score 4):

According to a [discussion](http://www.openrce.org/forums/posts/612) on OpenRCE, it seems that you cannot directly force IDA Pro to output an ".exe". What you can do is get it to produce a ".dif" and use that to patch the original ".exe".

To get IDA Pro to generate the ".dif":
 File->Produce file->Create